# Is there any free svn diff tool for Mac Instead of use command line 'svn diff'

Tags: macos, svn, diff

Using command line to view the diff code is really tough. Is there any GUI tool or just with gramma highlight command line tool to view the code changes of svn code line.

Comment: Finally, I found another good comparsion tool embeded in xcode.It's very easy. Just set the svn account info in xcode->preferences->accounts(turn on repository switch)
Now you are able to use xcode->Source Control->Commit...(here will list all the changed files with syntax highlight comparsion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, download and install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/), or from AppStore in OSX. Inside Xcode it have an application called FileMerge for diff and merge.

To configure `svn diff` for FileMerge, you can try [Wrapper to use OS X FileMerge when calling svn diff](https://gist.github.com/dtjm/523243). In short, add below line to `~/.subversion/config`

```
[helpers] 
diff-cmd = ~/bin/svn-diffwrap.sh
```

In ~/bin/svn-diffwrap.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/opendiff ${6} ${7}
```

chmod mod executable to svn-diffwrap.sh. You may need to provide full path instead of ~ if svn fails to find svn-diffwrap.sh.

Comment: Nice! Just a quick note: if you have spaces in your filenames, you'll want to add quotes around the ${6} and ${7}. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this quick and easy solution...

Comment: It works! But is anyone else getting a message "Couldn't load language spec for '<DVTSourceCodeLanguage:0x7fde51667720:'Xcode.SourceCodeLanguage.Swift'>'"?